RDS snapshot only restored writer instance
I restored an RDS aurora mysql snapshot , the original DB cluster has a reader and writer instance both. But when I took a snapshot of it and restored, i noticed that it only created a writer instance (where the backups are stored) not a reader one.
What could be the reason for this ?

It sounds like you used the AWS console to restore the snapshot. From the docs:
If you use the console to restore a DB cluster, then Amazon RDS automatically creates the primary DB instance (writer) for your DB cluster. 

You must explicitly create the reader instances after the cluster has been restored.
